# How to fix a broken embed link from Reddit

Tags: html, embedding, reddit, posts

When I copy the embed code from Reddit and paste into my HTML/CSS website, the embed looks to be incomplete as it includes only text without the embedded content.

I copied the exact embed code and pasted into into my website's page, but only text shows up. I've tried on other HTML websites and the same problem happens. Others in this class are having similar problems.

```
<blockquote class="reddit-card" data-card-created="1556725803"><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/FIFA/comments/bjezg8/will_this_barca_dutch_hyperlink_become_reality_in/">Will this Barca Dutch hyperlink become reality in FUT20?</a> from <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/FIFA">r/FIFA</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

[Will this Barca Dutch hyperlink become reality in FUT20?](https://www.reddit.com/r/FIFA/comments/bjezg8/will_this_barca_dutch_hyperlink_become_reality_in/) from [r/FIFA](http://www.reddit.com/r/FIFA)

Presumably, the entire Reddit post with image would embed cleanly on my site like Tweets and YouTube videos do.

Comment: It works fine here for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2brp58q7/. Any errors in your console? Content restrictions on your network?

Comment: @turnip thanks for the response. The Reddit posts embed but without the image, video, or other content -- there's only text. Other students in the class are experiencing the same thing, including on the Canvas LMS platform.

Comment: When I said it works fine for me I meant that in the example I posted I see the full post. Image and all. Which would suggest that the problem is related to your network or computer set up

Comment: It appears to be solved. The Reddit embed code will only work when the HTML page it was added to is published (not when previewing it in a browser).